# swift picker view row out of range if row greater the 15

Tags: pickerview

I am working with a multiple picker view in iOS.
Everything works perfectly only if the selected rows in a component is lower than 16.

In few words, even if the component has more than 16 items it looks that row can not point over the 15th item.

When a component points over the 15th, the pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) sets the error "Fatal error: Index out of range"